# I want to display different page using contents of mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, database

Actually, I have created an html page as a master page, I want to change the contents of body part by accessing database.
As for example,
If I have created a table with columns

```
pages_name, page_contents, page_id
about         somthing        1
services      somthing        2
```

Here, I am trying to do that If I change contents of my page for "about" then url will automatically change from "www.anything.com" to "www.anything.com/about" without creating another html file for "about".

How will change my url according to database content?

Answer (score 2):

You should use htaccess, mod rewrite

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Then route your pages like

```
$pages = array('register' => '/view/pages/register.php','something' => '/view/pages/some.php');
```

explode link to get name in array

```
$findPage = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

if link is www.homepage.com/register/ explode result will be register ($findPage[1])

Find current page

```
if(@array_key_exists($findPage[1], $allowed)) {

    include($allowed[$findPage[1]]); // if page found

}else{

    include($allowed['default']); // deafulat home page

}
```

Something like that. This works on ngix fine

Comment: But I had to use $findPage[2], but it worked.

Comment: It depends on link. try output echo $findPage[1] and $findPage[2]. and see the difference

Comment: Ya I did same. Thanks alot.

Comment: Is there anyway to get last word after / in url. For example, If I have url .. www.myhomepage.com/services/software/java then I get "java" in $findPage?

Comment: just count slashes. In this link are 3 slashes. $findPage[3].
http://lv1.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Use single html template and use get variable in URL to query different pages:

```
www.anything.com?pageid=3
```

then if you want to have more user and seo friendly URL user apache mod_rewrite to define redirections.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html